Why does updating state with useState in React not reflect the new value immediately?
I'm using React's useState hook to manage the state in my component. However, I've noticed that when I update the state, the new value doesn't seem to be reflected immediately within the same function call. Here's a simplified example:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const TestComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log(count); // This still logs the old value of count
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestComponent;

I know that state updates are asynchronous, but is there a way to get updated value immediately after calling setCount?
I know that using setTimeout with 0 delay or useEffect can help.
const increment = () => {
  setCount(count + 1);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(count); 
  }, 0);
};



useEffect(() => {
  console.log(count);
}, [count]);


You can prepare the next state and use that value?
const nextState = count + 1;
setCount(nextState)
// do something with nextState
